# Animate Popup on Close

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, popup

So I am having trouble animating a Popup in C#, and I am wondering what I am doing wrong. The popup animates on opening, does not animate on close. Do I have to set the PopupAnimation value to a new animation after it opens?

```
Popup popup = new Popup();
popup.AllowTransparency = true;
popup.StayOpen = false;
popup.PopupAnimation = PopupAnimation.Slide;
popup.IsOpen = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

To Animate a popup on close, you have to set the animation after the animation to open the popup.

```
popup.Opened += popup_Opened;  
void popup_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    popup.PopupAnimation = PopupAnimation.Fade;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? In my experience `PopupAnimation.Fade` has a closing animation, `PopupAnimation.Scroll` and `PopupAnimation.Slide` never. Have you tried this with the latter one too?

Comment: I tried it with PopupAnimation.Fade and I never got a closing animation. This is weird... perhaps it has something to do with how I set it up (although it seems pretty straight forward to me).